# Bug? Unable to undo a vote

Tags: bug

Scenario:

- I down vote an answer
- I hover over the down vote button and it says "Click again to undo down vote"
- I click on it
- It says "Your vote is now locked in until it is edited"

Is that a known bug?

If instead of clicking it again I click up vote it gives the person 2 points which is not usually what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Once a vote is locked in you can't unvote or do an opposite vote. If you can't undownvote, but you can upvote, then that would appear to be buggy.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when more than 5 minutes has passed between your first point and your second. You would find you would not be able to vote up either. The timeout applies to any vote change action. Only if the post is edited are previous voters allowed to change their votes. The lock doesn't kick in for the first 5 minutes to allow for correcting miss-clicks.

Comment: I don't see the value of locking the vote and regardless it is a bug since after the 5 minutes it still tells you you can change it.